# Loopback.js private model properties

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs

I have a small api with a model containing some properties. Half of the properties are being managed by the application itself and should not be *postable*, *editable* by the user sending an api request. The fields can be viewed only on `GET` requests.

Is there any way of masking those fields in the generated api docs (`swagger`) and also preventing the user from editing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-ACLs), in your model.json add a section for ACLs (Access Control Lists), as follows. I'm not sure what it will do to the docs, but it should make them readonly.

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "property": ["array", "of", "property", "names", "that", "are", "read",  "only"]
    }, 
    ...
]
```